# Java classpath, class not found

Tags: java, environment-variables

I'm trying to be able to do homework on my work computer for a Java class.  I see an old jdk is installed and I created a .bat to have my environment variables set up.  I can do a simple "HelloWord" example, but now when I try to do a simple example where I create a FileOutputStream object, I get class not found on my FileOutputStream.  Is this because my classpath is not set up, or because it can't find the io Package?  Thanks.

Edit:

```
Here is my work directory structure:
C:\dmd\jdk1.3.1
within jdk1.3.1 ->
bin
jre
lib
src (my files)

in my bin folder, i have this .bat file:
@echo off
SET TOOLS_HOME=c:\DMD
SET JAVA_HOME=%TOOLS_HOME%\jdk1.3.1
SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\BIN;%PATH%
SET CLASSPATH=.;
```

Comment: Give us a chance! Show us your `.bat` and/or your Java code. We're not telepaths!

Comment: mumble, java.io.FileOutputStream is part of java language since 1.0. I do not think that your jdk is older than that.

Comment: PATH looks good, JAVA_HOME is irrelevant, that means it's probably in the coding, as Tom Tresansky hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both - it cant find the IO package *because* your classpath isnt set up correctly. Do you have JAVA_HOME set correctly?

Comment: We don't know just how old this Java installation is, but since version 1.3 Java doesn't need or respect JAVA_HOME any more.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an import `java.io` statement in your source file using the FileOutputStream?

Comment: Or import java.io.FileOutputStream.  I thought mentioning you need to import from java.io might be a more general way of saying that both are acceptable.

Comment: Yes, the import java.io.* is there.